# where is angular-cli.json file in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3, angular6

I wanted to include a third party module( https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input ) in my app. They have asked us to insert their style sheet in angular-cli.json. Where I can I find this file in ionic 3 or any other way to add this stylesheet? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**By Default angular-cli.json does not present in ionic**